# include a php page based upon the value of a variable

Tags: php, function

I have made a function that take in the current page id and based on that result will either show two .php file or just one .php file.

Following is what I have written. Have I approached this in the right way?

```
<?php
function get_search_or_nav($page_id) {

    if(isset($page_id)) {

       $id = $page_id;
       $pages = array('home', 'thank-you');

       foreach($pages as $page){

          if($page==$id)
            $match = true;
       }
       if($match) {
          include("dir/file_1.php"); 
          include("dir/file_2.php"); 
       } 
       elseif (!$match) {
          include("dir/file_1.php");
       } 
   }
}
?>
```

The `$pages` variable holds the `$page_id` array i.e.`$pages = array('home', 'thank-you');`

each `.php` file has a `$page_id` i.e `index.php` has `$page_id = "home";`

The array is a list of the matching `$page_id`'s:

```
$pages = array('home', 'thank-you');
```

The call would then be:

```
get_search_or_nav($page_id);
```

Any help or advise would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just will do this:

```
$id = $page_id;
$pages = array('home', 'thank-you');

$match = in_array($id, $pages);
```

The iteration is not necessary

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. nice shortening of the iteration.

Just tested it and works like a charm, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for the `foreach` loop. PHP has inbuilt functions to handle what you want (`in_array()`): I'd change your function to something like this:

```
function get_search_or_nav($page_id) {

    if (isset($page_id)) {

        $id = $page_id;
        $pages = array('home', 'thank-you');

        // make sure file is in allowed array (meaning it exists)
        if(in_array(id, $pages)) {
            include("dir/file_1.php");
            include("dir/file_2.php");
            return true;
        } 
        // no match, so include the other file
        include("dir/file_1.php");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, yet another good solution, Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

You could approach your function in following way:

```
function get_search_or_nav($page_id) {

    if(isset($page_id)) {

       $pages = array('home', 'thank-you');

       // You could do this with for loop
       // but PHP offers in_array function that checks
       // if the given value exists in an array or not
       // if found returns true else false
       $match = in_array($page_id, $pages);


       // you are including this in either case
       // so no need to repeat it twice in both conditions
       include("dir/file_1.php");  

       // if match include file 2
       if ($match) {
           include("dir/file_2.php");
       }
    }

    // you might want to throw Exception or log error here
    // or just redirect to some 404 page or whatever is your requirement
}
```

[in_array reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply and link to doc's, this solution has really drilled down the code, like the way your thinking.... Also thanks for the great code commenting really help me understand your process. Thanks agin 5*